# How to set collision for octomap in moveit?

Tags: ros, moveit, octomap, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I input octomap to moveit first of run this command.

```
 rosrun octomap_server octomap_server_node cloud_in:=rtabmap/cloud_map
```

And move goal quadrotor when fixed framed is odom-combine. After that, I set fixed framed to map.(this is the only way I can move quadrotor) And do the plan. I found that quadrotor pass through the octomap. Octomap doesn’t have collision. How do I set collision for octomap?
in [this](https://imgur.com/6UAn1rW) picture,you can see quadrotor ignore octomap

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229074/how-to-set-collision-for-octomap-in-moveit?/) by [sean819](https://answers.ros.org/users/25461/sean819/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`octomap_server` is a standalone node belonging to [octomap_ros](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_ros) that is completely independent of moveit. The octomap library is used inside moveit (or more precise, the `move_group` node) for representing environment geometry, but that does not mean that loading a octomap into `octomap_server` automatically makes it known to moveit.

One option to feed the octomap to moveit is using the planning scene ROS API described in [this tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/planning_scene_ros_api_tutorial.html). Using that you can send new octomap collision geometry to moveit as part of the [moveit_msgs/PlanningSceneWorld](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/PlanningSceneWorld.html) message inside the [moveit_msgs/PlanningScene](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/PlanningScene.html) message.

Another (perhaps easier) option is to update the internal moveit octomap directly using your sensors, see [moveit 3D Perception/Configuration](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/perception_configuration.html).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sean819](https://answers.ros.org/users/25461/sean819/) on 2016-03-15**:
i think the first option is difficult for me(I am a beginner).So i didn't success.
Then i try the second one.But after i did all step in the tutorial and launch demo.launch.I got the warn message in [this](https://imgur.com/6XaTkMh) picture.

**Comment by [sean819](https://answers.ros.org/users/25461/sean819/) on 2016-03-15**:
i add the new question in [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/229159/error-about-moveit-in-using-octomap-for-collision/)

**Comment by [sean819](https://answers.ros.org/users/25461/sean819/) on 2016-03-27**:
I success now.but the weird thing is when i move xtion pro live. It didn't build 3D model. It build like a mass [here](https://imgur.com/HGr2X7a).How can i fix that?